# How can i reload youtube video in mainactivity?

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an android project. My project has a YoutubePlayer api. The video of EditText's video is taken and the video is shown. the following code works. But when I enter another id in the EditTex, the previous video is not replaced. The previous one looks the same. How can I fix this?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //find views by ID
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
        btnGo = (View) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);

        btnGo.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());

    }

    private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitialization() {
        return new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {

                    // loadVideo() will auto play video
                    // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(urlText.getText().toString().trim());

                    // Showing player controls with default mode
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "onInitializationFailure()",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Initializing video player with developer key
                youTubeView.initialize(API_KEY, onInitialization());
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `initialize()` again - once you get your success callback, retain a reference to the `YouTubePlayer` and use that to load subsequent videos:

```
private YouTubePlayer player = null;

//...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //find views by ID
    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
    btnGo = (View) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());

}

private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitialization() {
    return new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                //Keep doing what you're doing, and when finished...
                this.player = youTubePlayer;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            //...
        }
    };
}

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(player == null) {
                youTubeView.initialize(API_KEY, onInitialization());
            } else {
                player.loadVideo(urlText.getText().toString().trim());
                player.play();
            }
        }
    };
```